# How can I express that I have completed task given somebody in polite manner?

Tags: expressions, politeness

Somebody asked me to *rebase my github repository with his repository* and I did it as per his/her request. How can I express it in polite manner?

Some sentences running in my mind are:

> I did rebase with your master branch.

or

> I have rebased with your master branch.

Comment: Would "I have rebased to your master branch" make sense?

Comment: What's the grammatical role of *rebase*? If you've been asked to *rebase [your] github repository* it sounds like it's a regular verb. So why are you adding *did* before it and *with* after it? Just say *I rebased . . .* (Although *I have rebased* would also work—without the *with*.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How can I express that I have completed the (important) task given (optional: to me) by somebody (crucial)  in a polite manner (also important)?

Now the question makes more sense.

Just take this example. 
Your father asks you "Did you go to the college?"
You could simply reply "I went to the college."

Somebody asked you to rebase your github repo.
you could answer "I rebased my github repo as you asked."

Just use a simple past tense.